# Python selenium wait for page to load entirely

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to visit a list of 5000 websites and take screenshots. Before I take the screenshot I want the whole page to be loaded and the possible cookie pop up to be removed with the extension that I have given in the selenium driver.
The problem is that I do not know how to let selenium wait till the whole page and all of its content is loaded. The standard selenium wait functions do not work, because content can be generated in frames.

This is the function I have to visit a single url in the list:

```
def visit_url(driver, url):
     #Use Selenium to load the URL
     driver.get(f"http://{url}")
     # Wait for the page to load
     while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != "complete":
         time.sleep(1)
     driver.save_screenshot(f"data/screenshots/{url}.png")
```

But for some of the websites the screenshot is entirely white or it shows white blocks on places where content should be.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What's the point of this?  I cannot imagine a legitimate use for screenshots of 5,000 different websites.

Comment: I want to train a neural network with the data, so I need to visit lots of websites

Comment: But why screenshots?  That just makes the job harder.  Why not use the HTML?

Comment: I use the screenshots to label the websites, I save the html as well, but that is not relevant for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep() or search for a specific element on the site (that appears at the end of loading) using a while loop.

Comment: It should work for all 5000 websites, so I can not search for a specific element. Also, some websites can take a long time loading, so a longer sleep period is not optimal

Comment: Would </html> not be applicable?

Comment: No, lots of processing goes on after the `</html>` tag is read.  Heck, `document.load` doesn't even run until after the text is all in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until( 
                EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, path)))[0]
```

The "path" parameter is used to pass an XPath expression.  It waits for a specific element to be displayed, indicating that the page has finished loading. 
The "timeout" parameter specifies the duration to wait.  If the specified XPath element is not found within this time limit, an error will be reported.

Comment: I get that I can use this technique for one specific website. However, the question is how I can generalize this to all websites.

Comment: There is no universal mechanism, of course.  Practically every site uses a different mechanism for doing their cookie popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and make something like:

```
def visit_url(driver, url):
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

    driver.get(f"http://{url}")

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState")
            == "complete"
        )
    except TimeoutException as err:
        raise TimeoutError("Page not loaded") from err

    driver.save_screenshot(f"data/screenshots/{url}.png")
```

Comment: This would do the same as the code I have now, only with a time-out, so this won't improve it.